# If a cell contains a value, move another cell's value to other cell

Tags: excel

I need a formula for this :  if C3 cell's value is "X" or "any text", then have to move the B3 Cell's value to D3 cell.

Comment: You can't move a value from B3 this way; you can only copy it. If you want B3 to be empty afterwards, you'll need to use VBA. You can, however, use conditional formatting to make it appear invisible.

Answer (score 1):

put this in cell D3

```
=IF(OR(C3=x;C3 = "any text");B3;0)
```

Comment: You can replace the 0 with any value you want, its what happens when the logical expression is false.